# How to remove the object in nested array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to remove the object based on condition using javascript

if the `trans cost is > 200`, only have in `obj` else remove it

```
var obj1 = [{
  "id": "trans",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "100"
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "option": "credit",
  "cost": "300"
}, {
  "id": "service",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}]

var obj2 = [{
  "id": "trans",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "option": "credit",
  "cost": "300"
}, {
  "id": "service",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}]
//not working for obj2 returns []
function getData(obj) {
  return obj.filter(i => i.id !== "trans" && i.cost < 200).map(e => e.id);
}
var result = getData(obj1); //output: ["fund","service"]

var result = getData(obj2); //output: ["trans","fund","service"]
```

Comment: Replace `'&&` with `||` and `<` with `<=`.

Comment: You are using `<` on your code but on your description, you said `>`

Comment: On your get data function use;  return obj.filter(i =>  i.id==="trans" && i.cost >= 200);

Answer (score 0):

Just try filter with 2 conditions , it worked for me .

```js
var obj1 = [{
  "id": "trans",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "100"
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "option": "credit",
  "cost": "300"
}, {
  "id": "service",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}]

var obj2 = [{
  "id": "trans",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "option": "credit",
  "cost": "300"
}, {
  "id": "service",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}]

let x1= obj1.filter(o=>o.id==="trans" && o.cost>=200);
let x2= obj2.filter(o=>o.id==="trans" && o.cost>=200);

console.log(x1);
console.log(x2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filteredArray = obj1.filter(function(value){

    return id === 'trans' && value.cost > 200;
});
```

You can do like this. The filteredArray will only contain values > 200

Answer (score 0):

obj1.filter((transaction) => id === 'trans' && transaction.cost >= 200 );

obj2.filter(function(transaction){

```
return id === 'trans' && transaction.cost >= 200;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj1 = [{
  "id": "trans",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "100"
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "option": "credit",
  "cost": "300"
}, {
  "id": "service",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}]

var obj2 = [{
  "id": "trans",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "option": "credit",
  "cost": "300"
}, {
  "id": "service",
  "option": "bank",
  "cost": "200"
}]


var obj1_filter = obj1.filter(function(options_list){
    return options_list.id="trans" && options_list.cost>=200;
});

var obj2_filter = obj2.filter(function(options_list){
    return options_list.id='trans' && options_list.cost>=200
});

console.log(obj1_filter);
console.log(obj2_filter);
```

It's will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` as below -

```
var result = obj1.filter(item => item.id === "trans" && item.cost > 200);
```